# Keyboard not displaying when using Lock Task Mode with Device Admin

Tags: android, keyboard

Using lock task mode with Device Admin, I can't seem to get the soft keyboard to display.

Here's what I'm doing:

Two applications, one is an admin application, another is a regular user app. The goal is to lock down the phone to the user application. This involves setting it as the persistent preferred activity for home, using lock task mode, and setting the lock task packages.

```
// In my admin application
private static final String[] PACKAGES = new String[]{
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
    "com.android.settings",
    "com.xyz.myapp"
};

final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

devicePolicyManager.addPersistentPreferredActivity(adminComponent, intentFilter, componentName);
devicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(adminComponent, PACKAGES);

// In my user app main activity:
startLockTask();
```

We have some workflows in our application that require the user to adjust android settings, so the settings app is also permitted. After enabling admin (so that the two policies are enabled) and rebooting, the phone correctly opens my user application right away and the phone is locked to the single application. However, the keyboard will not appear for any EditTexts/text inputs. It's almost as if the system is trying to display the keyboard, because the back button arrow changes from the "Back" position (pointing left) to the "Close" position (pointing down).

I've experimented for days attempting to figure out the root cause but the only thing I've found is that the call to

```
setLockTaskPackages(...)
```

seems to be the culprit alongside lock task mode. I've attempted to add the keyboard application as permitted package in lock task mode but that made no difference. Additionally, the keyboard is prevented from opening from other permitted apps as well (android settings), so I do not believe this to be something incorrectly configured within my user app.

I've tested this on a Nexus 5X, Google Pixel, and Google Pixel 2. All running Stock 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

I know a long time has passed since you asked the question but maybe this helps someone else.

See the answers found here: [Android 8.1 (API 27) - Keyboard not showing in Kiosk-mode app after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676042/android-8-1-api-27-keyboard-not-showing-in-kiosk-mode-app-after-reboot/53692430#53692430)
Basically you should not do what you are doing: Don't start lock task mode when the device is locked because the user might not be able to unlock the device

That being said you can set FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED (deprecated since API 27) or FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD (deprecated since API 26) on all windows (even for the dialogs you open and need input) or call setShowWhenLocked on the activity (API 27+, haven't found a way to use this on dialogs).

Depending on your business flow you can do one of the following:

- disable keyguard altogether (set to None) before setting the device administrator
- set the proper flag(s) on all windows if you have access to sources for all apps that need keyboard input
- when you need keyboard input if device is locked (see KeyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked):

  - call stopLockTask
  - use KeyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard to request customer to unlock device
  - once the device was unlocked (KeyguardDismissCallback.onDismissSucceeded) call startLockTask to lock back the device
  - for security reasons you should consider locking back the device on exit and also request user to authenticate when accessing sensitive functionality from your lock screen (see KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent and KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure)